# Substring in JavaScript cuts off more than it should

Tags: javascript, substring

I am fairly new to JavaScript but today I stumbled upon a weird issue that I would really appreciate if someone could shed some light on for me.

I am working on a calculator in HTML. I have one function in js that I use for an onclick event on a div. That div works like a backspace button with the following code:

```
function remove() {
    var input = document.getElementById("input");

    input.innerHTML = input.innerHTML.substring(0, input.innerText.length - 1);

    // Check if comma exists
    if (input.innerHTML.indexOf(",") == -1) {
        comma = false;
    }
}
```

It removes the last added number from the innerHTML of my paragraph, like it should. However, doing that exact same thing in the following function somehow removes two characters from the paragraph instead of one:

```
function buttonOperator(operator) {
    var input = document.getElementById("input");
    var calc = document.getElementById("calculation");

    // Make sure new number isn't empty and fits into the calculation
    if (input.innerHTML != "") {
        // Bunch of code
    }
    else {
        // This line removes two characters instead of one
        calc.innerHTML = calc.innerHTML.substring(0, calc.innerText.length - 1);
        operators.pop();

        switch (operator) {
            case "÷":
                calc.innerHTML += "÷";
                operators.push("÷");
                break;
            
            case "×":
                calc.innerHTML += "×";
                operators.push("×");
                break;
            
            case "−":
                calc.innerHTML += "−";
                operators.push("−");
                break;
            
            case "+":
                calc.innerHTML += "+";
                operators.push("+");
                break;
        }
    }

    input.innerHTML = "";
    comma = false;
}
```

The function's purpose is to remove the already existing operator at the end of the paragraph and replace it with a new one. But removing the last character the same way I did in my remove function somehow removes two characters.

If I have:

```
98 +
```

Pressing, for example, plus again would leave the following:

```
98+
```

And again:

```
9+
```

etc.

I really don't understand how this can possibly happen. If someone could explain it to me for future reference I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: `innerHTML` and `innerText` are different, I would stick to `innerText`.

Comment: and if you're working with an input element you actually want `.value` and if it's the text content you want you're better off with `textContent` than `innerText` but certainly not mixing any of the above in a single calculation.

Comment: Why do you have two `case "+":` in your switch?

Comment: @Barmar  One is a divide, you using a dodgy font .. :)

Comment: Like stated, one is a divide, I can see how they blend together from afar. @pilchard I am using a paragraph, not an input. So I guess using textContent or or innerText only is the way to go?

Comment: I changed all innerHTML to innerText. Now it only removes 2 characters the first time. If I keep changing operator after that it only removes one. How is that even possible?

Comment: Depends on your markup. innerText doesn’t return everything depending on markup, so the first time whatever irregularities get replaced and t he n it stablizes.

Comment: Using innerText for if-statements and changes (like removing last character) and innerHTML for adding text seems to work. I am still rather confused tho.